# Pusho notification Web App progressive web app

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Estou criando um progressive web app porém não consegui realizar as push notification como está na documentação. Gostaria de saber se tem um modo mais prático para fazer fazer push notifications.

Comment: Você poderia passar o código utilizado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução.
Na realidade precisava checar a permissão como Notification.resquestPermission()
E também precisava de um certificado SSL para registrar o service-work.